# extract specific data from log file

Tags: vbscript

i have a log file , from which i need to extract everything in between "Ath response is as follow :" till "End of ath response", I am fairly new to vbs , can please someone suggest ow to achieve this.

Sample log:-

```
[2016-06-03 00:13:32,376] [Thread-125] [ath.SeAhRqTyp] INFO- [338aacca-69ca-43ca-9ad1-c623f16ba56f]-outgoing Request is as follows: -
[2016-06-03 00:13:32,376] [Thread-125] [ath.SeAhRqTyp] INFO- [338aacca-69ca-43ca-9ad1-c623f16ba56f]-<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><out:ARequest </out:ARequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] [Thread-125] [ath.EvResp] INFO- [338aacca-69ca-43ca-9ad1-c623f16ba56f]-Ath response is as follow :
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] S
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] A
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] M
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] P
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] L
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] E
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] T
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] E
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] S
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] T
[2016-06-03 00:13:33,548] [Thread-125] [ath.EvResp] INFO- [338aacca-69ca-43ca-9ad1-c623f16ba56f]-End of ath response
```

Comment: You should at least post what did you tried as code so far !

Comment: AutoIt and VBS are not the same. Tell us what you want and in which language. Then try something. Post it. We try to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It reads in a file named **myLog.log** and outputs a file named **result.log**.

```
option explicit
dim fso, myLog, oneLine, insideBlock, textBlock, markerFound
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set myLog = fso.OpenTextFile("MyLog.Log")
insideBlock = false
markerFound = false
textBlock = ""
do while not myLog.AtEndOfStream
    oneLine = myLog.readLine
    markerFound = instr(lcase(oneLine),"ath response")>0
    if insideBlock then
      if not markerFound then
        textBlock = textBlock & oneLine & vbcrlf
      else
        exit do
      end if
    else
      insideBlock = markerFound
    end if
Loop
myLog.Close
set myLog = fso.CreateTextFile("result.log")
myLog.Write(textBlock)
myLog.Close
```